# rich:tab with switchType as "client" not submitting when tabPanel has switchType as "ajax"

Tags: jsf-2, tabs, richfaces, tabpanel

I am using richfaces tabPanel with switchType as default (Ajax). I need to have one tab with `switchType="client"` since it has upload file component and I need to preserve the value on tab switch. When below form is submitted, all the values in `tab1` and `tab2` gets updated but setter do not get called for component values in `tab3`.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
<h:form encType="multipart/form-data">
    <rich:tabPanel>
        <rich:tab header="tab1">
            ...
        </rich:tab>
        <rich:tab header="tab2">
        ...
        </rich:tab>
        <rich:tab header="tab3" switchType="client">
            <h:inputText id="data" value="#{backingBean.value}"/>
            <t:inputFileUpload id="file" value="#{backingBean.file}"/>
        </rich:tab>
    </rich:tabPanel>
</h:form>
```

Comment: I've never seen usage of `switchType` directly on `rich:tab`... Don't understand how it could work. Of course it will work on `rich:tabPanel`.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/vdldoc/rich/tab.html Here is the VDL link that shows any particular tab can have its own switch type. I can see that in principal it is working and preserving the value of uploaded file on client side but it is not getting submitted to back end.

Comment: One idea is to try execute="@form" on the button/component you use to submit the form, or even more tricky, like execute="@form data file".